# How do I generate simulated orbits with Skyfield?

Tags: skyfield

I have the orbital parameters for multiple simulated orbits. I want to feed this into Skyfield so that I can see how the distances between the satellites (and to ground stations) vary with time.

It seems that Skyfield only supports creating a EarthSatellite instance via a TLE. 
Do I have to fake a TLE to create my 'own' satellites?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [poliastro](https://github.com/poliastro/poliastro) instead! Far more convenient.